# How to attach a non-exportable client certificate to a request using C# HttpClient?

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate

I have a non-exportable client certificate in the "client" computer's Local Computer / Personal certificates store, and I want to use this certificate for client authentication when making web requests using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.

I have tried using `HttpClientHandler` thus:

```
var subject = /* Distinctive subject name of the certificate known to exist in the store */;
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subject, true);
// Known/verifiable at this point that certificates[0] is the correct client cert
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificates[0]);
using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(URL.Text);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // ... etc...
}
```

... but the `GetAsync` call throws an exception with the message:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I have been able to verify that this is a client-side issue and that the correct certificate is being returned from the store.

- I have tested this code against known working endpoints (which require a certificate); other clients work.
- I know the certificate is valid because it is successfully used for client authentication by other client code (sources I don't currently have at my disposal)

As I understand it, I am only attaching the public portion (because it is non-exportable), so the authentication is failing. There must surely be a way to use a private, non-exportable key for such a purpose, correct? How do I do it?

Comment: The issue is not in the export status of the private key. I would suspect that your client does not have permissions to private key stored in a machine store. You need either, move certificate to current user (which runs your client) or grant access to private key.

Comment: Found that it works if I run the client app as Administrator, confirming that the issue is related to permissions.